# How to gather data about venues' ratings using Foursquare API

Tags: python, foursquare

I need help with my homework. I want to get the ratings of a specific number of venues using Foursquare API.

Tis is what I came up with so far

```py
venues_ids= df['id']
ratings=[]
for venue_id in venues_ids.values.tolist():
    url = 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/{}?client_id={}&client_secret={}&v={}'.format(venue_id, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, VERSION)
    result = requests.get(url).json()
    try:
        venues_rating=result['response']['venues']['rating']
        ratings=ratings+[venues_rating]
    except IndexError:
        print('No data available for id=',ID)
ratings
```

I'm expecting a list with all the ratings for the specific ids. However, I get the error message---- KeyError: 'venues'

Any tip would be appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
venues_rating=result['response']['venue']['rating'] // not 'venues'
```

- Not all venues will have a rating.

Comment: hey! Thanks a lot for checking! Unfortunately, I get the same error even if I change to 'venue'. This time it shows---KeyError: 'venue'